# How to Get the value of options in multiselect div

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

I want to retrieve the multi-select values after selected it
this is the code in aspx page

```
<div class="multiselect" id="lblMultiSelect" runat="server" multiple="multiple" data-target="multi-0">
    <div class="title noselect">
        <span class="text">Select</span>
        <span class="close-icon">&times;</span>
        <span class="expand-icon">&plus;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container"  runat ="server" id="t">
      <% For v As Integer = 0 To Years_dt.Rows.Count - 1 %>
         <% Dim selectedYear As String %>
             <% selectedYear = Years_dt.Rows(v).Item("COLUMN_NAME")%>
                 <option style="color:black;" value="<%Response.Write(selectedYear) %>" >                                                          
                    <% Response.Write(selectedYear)%> </option>
                  <%next %>
          </div>
</div>
```

in the vb, I want to for each in these values and there is an option to select and delete the selection like this
[how the dropdown list looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZngPU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so no one is biting here.

I don't have a bootstrap example, but I can recommend an approach that works quite well.

The only downside to this example?
Well, you need jQuery (that you have almost for sure).

Then you need to add jQuery.UI. I high recommend jQuery.UI since it has some REALLY nice dialog boxes, and popups that are great for user inputs (ok dialog or confirm, or just popping up a display).

The next thing you need is a check box add-in. Now I am not "huge" on having to go grab some special control for this and that. So, we want to try and find some simple bit of code that will allow use to use "existing" code approaches that we always used. This can save huge time, as for things like a drop down, list box etc., we can't go off and do some white paper research on how to do this (project will get too bogged down).

So, I am going to suggest this library here:

This is a simple and SINGLE JavaScript file you can add to your project. Once done, then you get a great looking mutli-select drop down box. But MORE important, you can use a list box on the web form (the add-in will convert/flip it to a drop own. But, you STILL get to use the standard event model for the list box - this includes autopost back and all of the standard code you already know!

so, say we want a mutli-select dropdown to say select form a city list. Then we use that to display say hotels in that city.

So, we drop in a listbox, and say a search button.

We have this markup:

```
 <div style="float:left;">
   <h3>Select City(s)</h3>
   <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static"
      DataValueField = "ID"  
      DataTextField = "City" 
      multiple="true"  SelectionMode="Multiple" >
   </asp:ListBox>
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
   <h3>Search</h3>
   <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search Hotels" Height="28px" Width="123px" />
</div>

<div style="clear:both;height:20px"></div>
<div style="width:30%">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table"></asp:GridView>

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        c3 = $('#ListBox1')
        c3.dropdownchecklist({
            width: 300,height: 28,
            icon: {
                placement: 'right',
                toOpen: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s',
                toClose: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-e'
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

So that extra script part? That is the add-in.

And our code because this is standard .net controls?

Really easy!!!

this:

So, the code to load up the multi-select is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadCombo()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadCombo()

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT ID,City from City ORDER BY City DESC")

    ListBox1.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL)
    ListBox1.DataBind()
    ListBox1.Items.Insert(0, "")      ' add blank row

End Sub
```

So now click Click on dropdown, and select a few like this:

[image]

(also, having check boxes is a VERY helpful UI, since users will INSTANT know that they can select more then one.

Ok, so now we have this:

[image]

Now, when we click on the button, we was to get/loop the choices.

but, we want to take those choices, and feed them into that gridview.
We could actually save a wee bit of code, but lets keep the code sql injection safe, and not concatenate the user input values.

So, the basic loop to get/check the selected values is now this:

```
   For Each MySel As ListItem In ListBox1.Items
        If MySel.Selected Then
            debug.print (MySel.Text)   ' gets the display text value
            debug.print (MySel.Value)  ' gets the value
       End If
    Next
```

Again, really simple to get both "display" value, and say the PK id value if that is the hidden value in the droop down.

So, lets take the above loop, and build a query to fill the grid:

```
Protected Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click

    Dim sWhere As String = ""

    Dim cmdSQL As New _
      SqlCommand("SELECT HotelName, City, Province, Active FROM tblHotels ")

    For Each MySel As ListItem In ListBox1.Items
        If MySel.Selected Then
            If sWhere <> "" Then sWhere &= ","
            With cmdSQL.Parameters
                sWhere &= "@" & .Count
                .Add("@" & .Count, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = MySel.Text
            End With
        End If
    Next
    cmdSQL.CommandText &= "WHERE City IN(" & sWhere & ") ORDER BY HotelName"
    GridView1.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL)
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

So all we did above was build City IN (@0, @1, @2...N) choices into the string, but note how we ALWAYS take the browser input and use a strong type parameter as per above.

Ok, so with above, click the button, and we get this:

[image]

Is that not great?

Note how little markup.

Note how we wrote standard vb code behind to fill the listbox,

And note how we used standard code to fill the grid.

This approach thus saved

HUGE amounts of "messy" and hard to read mark-up. (I can't make heads or tails by looking at your mark-up. Now I suppose what you have is ok, but its hard to read, and besides, in my example, we used plain jane controls. I did add CssClass= "table" to the grid, and bootstrap does its magic for you (the output gird look great!!).

So, you need the add-in.

It can be found here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/dropdownchecklist/files/

From above, JUST grab and add this file to your project (scripts folder):

```
ui.dropdownchecklist-1.5-min.js
```

I don't know if you using a master page, but as noted, you need:

```
jQuery
jQuery.UI
```

And of course I am using boot strap.

The documentation to use the droop down check box is here:

http://dropdownchecklist.sourceforge.net/

However, you only really need what I posted above.

In above, I also became rather tired of having to build connection and load a data table, so I do have this global vb helper routine to allow nice and easy grabbing of data into tables:

```
Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand) As DataTable

    Dim rst As New DataTable
    Using cmdSQL
        cmdSQL.Connection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        cmdSQL.Connection.Dispose()
    End Using

    Return rst
End Function
```

So, the beauty of above is we really have very little markup. Were able to drop in a list box (I used listbox in place of dropdown list, since a drop down list does NOT support multiple selects. But, note how filling of the data, and then looping with server side code works quite much like all your other code does - so it easy to adopt.

I also do NOT suggest you use server tags and inter-mingle that vb.net code in the markup page - its REALLY hard to write, hard to debug, and as above shows, you much better off to try and leverage the built in controls, and thus not even have to "loop" code to fill say a simple grid, or dropdown - use the great parts about .net, and that is those controls that can be filled up with great ease.

Now that's not a lot of markup. But we have a listbox, a button and a gridview.